# Dataset to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dataset (.txt) for applying SVM.A snapshot is given below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hh3Oh.png)

Here the first element is the corresponding label of a class. and rests are the feature and value pair. I need to carry out the labels in a separate file. And transform the feature value pair into 2d numpy array. Can anyone help me with python?

Answer (score 3):

This is the *LIBSVM* file format. You can read it with the function [sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file.html) within [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html).